# How to get RUSER and EUSER of the process (FreeBSD)

Tags: process, freebsd, ps

I have tried this but doesn't work `ps -eo euser,ruser,suser,fuser,f,comm,label | grep processname`

can anyone show me the right way to do this?

Comment: grep -i pid /proc/`pidof processname`/status ?

Comment: put `pidof procesname` in a pair of backtick

Comment: @SHW will try and get back

Comment: @SHW noway to do with the PS itself?

Comment: @SHW No doesn't kick in i tried this "grep -i pid /proc/`0000`/status" and grep -i 0000 /proc/`0000`/status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to map Linux `ps` options and field name to FreeBSD `ps` options and keywords : this is one of the main obvious differences between a linux-like system and a BSD-style one.

First the `-e` option on FreeBSD `ps` means *"Display the environment as well"*.
What you want is in fact displaying all processes, that is `-ax` for FreeBSD;
`-x` is to display also processes without a controlling terminal (kernel processes and daemons) and the default behavior is not to display them.

Regarding Linux `ps` about per field selection (from `man ps`):

```
 euser      EUSER    effective user name. This will be the textual user ID,   if it can be obtained and the field width
                     permits, or a decimal representation otherwise. The n option can be used to force the decimal
                     representation. (alias uname, user).
 ruser      RUSER    real user ID. This will be the textual user ID, if it can be obtained and the field width permits,
                    or a decimal representation otherwise.
 suser      SUSER    saved user name. This will be the textual user ID, if it can be obtained and the field width permits,
                     or a decimal representation otherwise. (alias svuser).
 fuser      FUSER    filesystem access user ID. This will be the textual user ID, if it can be obtained and the field
                     width permits, or a decimal representation otherwise.
 f          F        flags associated with the process, see the PROCESS FLAGS section. (alias flag, flags).
 comm       COMMAND  command name (only the executable name). Modifications to the command name will not be shown.
                     A process marked <defunct> is partly dead, waiting to be fully destroyed by its parent. The output in
                     this column may contain spaces. (alias ucmd, ucomm). See also the args format keyword, the -f option,
                     and the c option.
                     When specified last, this column will extend to the edge of the display. If ps can not determine
                     display width, as when output is redirected (piped) into a file or another command, the output width
                     is undefined. (it may be 80, unlimited, determined by the TERM variable, and so on) The COLUMNS
                     environment variable or --cols option may be used to exactly determine the width in this case. The w
                     or -w option may be also be used to adjust width.
 label      LABEL    security label, most commonly used for SE Linux context data. This is for the Mandatory Access
                     Control ("MAC") found on high-security systems.
```

From FreeBSD `ps` manual about per keyword selection:

```
 uid        effective user ID (alias euid)
 user       user name (from UID)
 ruid       real user ID
 ruser      user name (from ruid)
 svuid      saved UID from a setuid executable
 state      symbolic process state (alias stat)
 comm       command
 label      MAC label
```

There is no obvious FreeBSD equivalent to *fuser*, so let's skip it.

So, in your case it would translate to:

`ps -axo user,ruser,svuid,state,comm,label  |grep <process_name>`

Comment: phenomenal Answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

And here's how to do it without `ps`:

```
awk '{ 
    if ("awk" == $1) 
        print "PID:",$2,"EUID:",$12,"EGID:",$13,"Groups:",$14; 
}' /proc/*/status
```

Substitute for `"awk"` in the `if` test as appropriate.  Remove the `if` test and substitute a specific process ID for `*` if you want to inspect a specific process.

Comment: WARNING: procfs is not mounted by default on a FreeBSD system AND there is no SVUID or RUID info into the `/proc/<current_proc>/status` meta file !

Comment: It is if one has installed TrueOS/PC-BSD.